# laravel passport generate token in db transaction

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-passport, laravel-api

i want to create a new user and generate password grant token inside a db transaction like this :

```
 $createdUser= DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        $createdUser=$this->userService->create($request->validated()['user']);
        $accessToken=$this->userService->generateUserToken($request->validated()['email'], $request->validated()['password']);
    });
```

the generateUserToken function send the /OAuth/token to get a new token but passport send MySQL query to select the created user which is not in DB because the transaction is not committed yet...
when I generate the token outside the transaction it works perfectly.
any idea on how to accomplish this?